# Taking the average of values of a column in one file, grouped by a factor in another file AWK

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

This problem is hard to describe in one sentence, so forgive me if the title doesn't capture what I write below..

I have two files, the first file (file1.txt) contains:

```
Chr1    1   0
Chr1    2   0
Chr1    3   3
Chr1    4   0
Chr1    5   5
Chr1    6   0
Chr1    7   0
Chr1    8   0
Chr1    9   0
Chr1    10  7
Chr1    11  0
Chr1    12  0
Chr1    13  0
Chr1    14  9
Chr1    15  0
Chr1    16  0
Chr1    17  0
Chr1    18  0
Chr1    19  0
Chr1    20  0
Chr2    1   0
Chr2    2   0
Chr2    3   0
Chr2    4   9
Chr2    5   10
Chr2    6   1
Chr2    7   0
Chr2    8   0
Chr2    9   0
Chr2    10  0
```

Chr1 and Chr2 stand for chromosomes (column1) and column2 contain the positions on the chromosome. Notice how the number always starts from 1 and then goes up to an larger number but unknown number (for Chr1, it ends at 20). The third column contains a count at that chromosome and position.

File2.txt looks like this:

```
Chr1    1   10
Chr1    5   15
Chr1    10  20
Chr1    15  25
Chr5    1   10
```

It specifies windows that are 10 positions apart (will be in the sorted order: the starting position goes up in increments of 5, but the window size is 10).

---

I need to average the count within each window.

The window for Chr1 position 1 to Chr1 position 10
has combined count 0+0+3+0+5+0+0+0+0+7=15
So the average is 15/10(size of the window) = 1.5

The window for Chr1 position 5 to Chr1 position 15
has combined count 5+0+0+0+0+7+0+0+0+9+0=21
So the average is 21/11(size of the window) = 1.909

The window for Chr1 position 10 to Chr1 position 20
has combined count 7+0+0+0+9+0+0+0+0+0+0=16
So the average is 16/11(size of the window) = 1.454

The window for Chr1 position 15 to Chr1 position 25 (last 5 positions are out of range)
has combined count 0+0+0+0+0+0=0
So the average is 0

*The window for Chr5 position 1 to Chr5 position 10 (no records in file1.txt)
So the average is 0*

The output should be:

```
Chr1    1   10  1.5
Chr1    5   15  1.909
Chr1    10  20  1.454
Chr1    15  25  0
Chr5    1   10  0
```

*Notice how Chr2 isn't in the output file because there weren't any windows specified for Chr2 in file2*..

I've coded something in perl to solve the problem, however, it is rather slow due to the large size of file1.txt. Is this problem solvable using awk? I'm hoping it might offer a faster (and shorter) solution..

I'm guessing the solution would involve an associative array, but so far all I've figured out is how to join on column1 and 2, which is not even close to solving the problem..

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]=$3;next}{ print a[$1,$2]}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Or is this problem not suited for awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading the data from the first file into the array properly. Then when you read the second file, you need to loop through the values selected by the range, calculating the average.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]=$3;next}
     { total = 0;
       for(i = $2; i <= $3; i++) total += a[$1,i];
       print $1, $2, $3, total/($3-$1+1);
     }' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. Except I think it's supposed to be total/($3-$2+1)?